# Python exception: error Bad compression level

Tags: python, exception, compression

So I am trying to write a program that encodes(and decodes) a string with this formula:

```
Decode: b64 decode -> zlib decode -> decoded string
```

Here is how i coded it:

```
def decode_level(level_data: str) -> str:
    base64_decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(level_data.encode())
    decompressed = zlib.decompress(base64_decoded, 15 | 32)
    return decompressed.decode()
```

But how do I reverse it?
I mean how do I encode that string?
I have tried this:

```
def encodeLevelData(lvlData: str) -> str:
    eData = lvlData.encode() # eData -> encoded data
    compressed = zlib.compress(eData, 15 | 32)
    b64decoded = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(compressed)
    return b64decoded
```

But it gives me an error on this line:

```
-> Exception has occurred: Bad compression: levelcompressed = zlib.compress(eData, 15 | 32)
```

Why does this error happen? And how do I fix it?
Here is the string that im trying to encode: https://pastebin.com/4Dkz07yY

Comment: [`compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.compress) takes a value from -1 to 9. You provide a value of `47` (`15 | 32`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says the level is bad because the level is bad. You should have just gone to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) to see that the level for `zlib.compress()` can only be in `-1..9`.

It looks like you trying to give a `wbits` value to the `level` parameter. There *is no* `wbits` parameter for `zlib.compress()`. If you want to specify `wbits` then you need to use `z = zlib.compressobj()` and `z.compress()`. (Again, actually reading the documentation is a huge help here.)

`wbits = 15 | 32` for decompression means to look for either a zlib header, *or* a gzip header. That can't be given for compression, since you need to say what you want. (Ooh, look! That's in the documentation as well.) If you want a zlib header, use `wbits = 15`. If you want a gzip header, use `wbits = 15 | 16`.